# ConcurrentModificationException while iterating Map

Tags: java, android, dictionary, concurrency, iteration

I have the following code below

```
Map<String, Integer> buyingItemEnumerationMap = this.toBuyItemEnumeration;
for (Entry<String, Integer> item : buyingItemEnumerationMap.entrySet()) {
   if(RandomEngine.boolChance(50)){ //will delete?
    buyingItemEnumerationMap.remove(item.getKey());
   }
   if(buyingItemEnumerationMap.size() == 1){
    break;
   }
}
```

now I am working with an android game and the code above is running in multithreaded way. Now I am having an exception which is `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. I already researched on how I can solve the problem but seems not to work on me.
 What I am doing on the code above is to **remove an entry randomly**. How can I implement it there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot remove an element from a collection while iterating it unless you use an `Iterator`.

This is what's causing the exception.

```
buyingItemEnumerationMap.remove(item.getKey());
```

Use [Iterator#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) to remove an element while iterating over your collection like

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = 
                           buyingItemEnumerationMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry<String, Integer> item = iterator.next();
   if(RandomEngine.boolChance(50)){ //will delete?
      iterator.remove();
   }
   //..
}
```

***EDIT** : (in response to OP's comment)*
Yes, the deletions done through `Iterator#remove()` over the `Set` returned by [HashMap.entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) would reflect in the underlying `Map` as the `Set` is backed by it. Quoting the JavaDoc here:

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so *changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa*.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iter = this.toBuyItemEnumeration;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    if (some-condition){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

**HOW IT WORKS ?**

The javadoc for `ConcurrentModificationException` says:

*If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.*

The field `int expectedModCount` is initiated to be equal to the field `protected transient int modCount = 0;` (and this is valid for Collections and Maps), and `modCount` keeps track of the structural modifications over the object. If `modCount` at some point of the iteration gets unequal  to `expectedModCount`, then a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

With using `Iterator` to make structural changes over the map/collection (like removing elements), we make sure that the removal operation will be executed properly, e.g. the `modCount` will be equal to the `expectedModCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator in the forEach loop and use iterator.remove();

Answer (score 0):

Yes `you can't delete entries in a Map while traversing it by it's own property`. different approch.