# Call functions that require the main thread from different fibers

Tags: c, ruby, multithreading, ui-thread, fibers

There are lots of functions that are supposed to be called from the main thread.  In my limited experience, these are mostly UI functions.

Examples:

- [-[UIApplication delegate] must be called from main thread only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081731/uiapplication-delegate-must-be-called-from-main-thread-only))
- [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372451/java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-on-the-main-thread)
- [Drawing to window from child thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028838/drawing-to-window-from-child-thread)

Suppose I have a fiber library that creates "threads" with set/get context. Is it safe to call main thread only functions from any fiber started from the main OS thread?

I think it is fine since the OS doesn't know about my fibers, but I'm not sure.  I would test this, but the results would not be definitively since it might work but be relying on undefined behavior.

Edit: marking this question C since set/get context are C functions, although as mentioned in the comments I think it may apply to programs written in other languages as well.

Comment: Is there a specific language this question is tied to?

Comment: @merlin2011 setcontext is a C function, but I think conceptually this could apply to any language with a fiber library

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing fundamental about the main thread; these restrictions you're talking about are specific to run-times.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think all of these runtimes distinguish threads with thread ids (what else could it be) so if that's true then there could be a general answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can call any function in your program from any context. Note that using `getcontext` and `setcontext` are not making real "threads", and you're not getting any parallel processing with this - you're only getting scheduling. That's why it will work, no matter if it's a UI function or not. It's basically just a goto that works cross-function. To quote the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) directly:

> If the context was obtained by a call of getcontext(), program
>   execution continues as if this call just returned.

That means if I write

`... code ...
getcontext(&cxt);
... code ...
setcontext(&cxt);`

Then when I reach `setcontext`, the state that I go to is *identical* to when the function `getcontext` just returned. There is no perceivable difference (Of course, you may have changed memory values in the mean time, but that's beside the point). The manpage has a similar guarantee with `makecontext`, but with the note that it'll redirect you after the given function finishes execution.

The examples you give are in higher level programming langauges, which have a lot more complexity, and thus are not as simple as `setcontext`/`getcontext` in `C`. The Java Error you posted seems to actually be a distinct OS thread, and same with the third example. The first example looks like it might be a fake thread but of course there are hidden complexities which might prevent UI calls from working (Since they interact with external APIs).

That's why threading in JS is so easy: because the threads aren't real. What you lose in parallel performance you gain in being able to call anything anywhere from your dispatched functions and ajax calls.

If you know your fiber library is really only using `getcontext` and `setcontext`, then you'll be fine. The library might do something else though, so it would be good to verify with the library writers in such a situation.